# When does $n$ divide $\binom{n}{i}$ for all $i$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For what $n$ is it true that $n$ divides $\binom{n}{i}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$?

When $n$ is prime, the statement is true, which we can see by looking at the expansion of $\binom{n}{i}$. But what about when $n$ is composite?

Comment: See [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem).

Comment: @Lucian: Don't you need [Kummer's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem) to deal with the case where $n$ is a prime power? Or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "never".  Suppose $n=pm$, where $m>1$ and $p$ is prime.  We have $${n\choose p}=\frac{(pm)(pm-1)\cdots (pm-p+1)}{p!}$$
Let $\nu_p(x)$ denote the $p$-counting [valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). Note that none of $(pm-1),(pm-2),\ldots, (pm-p+1)$ are multiples of $p$.  $$\nu_p\left({n\choose p}\right)=\nu_p(pm)-\nu_p(p!)=1+\nu_p(m)-1=\nu_p(m)<1+\nu_p(m)=\nu_p(n)$$

Hence, $n$ has at least one more $p$ as a factor than does ${n\choose p}$.

Answer (score 4):

let $n=p^\alpha k$ with $\alpha,k\geq1$ and $p\nmid\alpha$ then $\binom{n}{p^\alpha}=\frac{(p^\alpha+1)(p^\alpha+2)\dots (n-1)(n)}{1\cdot2\cdot\dots (n-p^\alpha)}=\frac{(n-p^\alpha+1)\dots (n-1)(n)}{1\cdot 2 \cdots p^\alpha}$ notice both the numerator and the denominator are congruent factor by factor mod $p^\alpha$, since none of those factors are divisible by $p^{\alpha+1}$ this gives us all the divisibility info we need, thus that division is not a multiple of $p$.

Comment: How do you know none of the factors are divisible by $p^{\alpha+1}$? For example, when $k=p+1$, then $n-p^{\alpha}=p^{\alpha+1}$.

Comment: is it clear now?